# JQuery add Input fields and numerate them

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm looking for a JQuery code which creates input fields dynamically.. I found this code and it's kind of the thing I want

```
$(function() {
    var input = $('<input type="text" />');
    var newFields = $('');
    $('#qty').bind('blur keyup change', function() {
        var n = this.value || 0;
        if (n + 1) {
            if (n > newFields.length) {
                addFields(n);
            } else {
                removeFields(n);
            }
        }
    });

    function addFields(n) {
        for (i = newFields.length; i < n; i++) {
            var newInput = input.clone();
            newFields = newFields.add(newInput);
            newInput.appendTo('#newFields');
        }
    }

    function removeFields(n) {
        var removeField = newFields.slice(n).remove();
        newFields = newFields.not(removeField);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eC2WC/)

But I would like to have the fields numerated, like this:

- #1 FIELD
- #2 FIELD
- #3 FIELD

I've already tried my best and I've really searched for a long time but I haven't found anything that helps me. I hope someone can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addFields(n) {
        for (i = newFields.length; i < n; i++) {
            var newInput = $("<div>#"+(i+1)+"</div>").append(input.clone());
            newFields = newFields.add(newInput);
            newInput.appendTo('#newFields');
        }
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eC2WC/372/)**